# Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight Unique device Id

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I would like to know if there is a way to find unique device ID for Windows phone 8.1 Silverlight applications. I tried to use

Windows.Phone.System.Analytics.HostInformation.PublisherHostId

that I found on one of simillar questions for this topic, but I got this error:

http://pokit.org/get/?a9872a6ecf1714d138a71d835ccb8e27.jpg

I went to Package.appxmanifest file and I couldn't find this option to chek under Capabillities section.

My question is : Is there a way to get an unique id in form of a string from application, so that I could use that string on my online database to know from which device the request came, since I have enabled multiple profiles in my application on same devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an answer to the question. It turns out that I can use the Windows.Phone.System.Analytics.HostInformation.PublisherHostId method, but I have to check the ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE capabillity in WMAppManifest.xml file. That file can be found under Properties of Windows phone 8.1 Silverlight application.

Answer (score 0):

You can instead use [GetPackageSpecificToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.hardwareidentification.getpackagespecifictoken.aspx) .

```
HardwareToken packageSpecificToken;
packageSpecificToken = Windows.System.Profile.HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
IBuffer buffer = packageSpecificToken.Id;
string id = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToHexString(buffer);
```

This Id can change with hardware changes. Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431) for further information and how to tolerate the changes.

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried, but HardwareToken is available only on RT applications, and as I have written, i need something for Silverlight application.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a [DeviceInformation class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.ASPx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1), which has a [id property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.id.ASPx) according to the documentation at least, it is "A string representing the identity of the device.".

Comment: It's not quite useful for me , since I need to use this regularly to find that Id whenever the user needs something from the database, and in this case it's often. Anyhow, thank you for your answer. If you have more suggestions, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I usually just place a Guido in **ApplicationData.LocalSettings** and use it as an identifier.

If I want to identify the user "globally" I put it into **RoamingSettings** (with some extra care for the synchronization).

Yes those come up as "new" devices, when users reinstall the app, but that usually makes not difference for me and it respects the users privacy as far as possible.